# Can a CiviRule trigger off a Contribution Custom Field entry?

Tags: civirules

We have a custom profile "Other Details" that is for Contributions. When someone inputs information into the custom fields, I would like to trigger a Civi Action to do something with that information.

Is there any way to trigger off of that custom table? If I trigger off Contribution is Added, it is too early and has not yet written to the custom table. So I need the trigger to happen off the custom table.

Answer (score 1):

Right now there is no trigger on custom data for a contribution. You could try though with the "contribution is changed" trigger and see if you can pinpoint your custom field/data with the "field value comparison" conditions?

Obviously you are quite welcome to either add the trigger yourself, or fund CiviCooP (or any other partner that is familiar with CiviRules) adding the trigger :-)

Comment: How much would it be to fund a new trigger?

Comment: Drop me a mail at erik.hommel@civicoop.org? (erik dot hommel at civicoop dot org)? I guess it is about 8-12 hours of work.